# Pandas 1.0.0 incompatibility with python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pip

I have a virtual environment with `python 3.5.2` installed.

If I try to install Pandas with a fake version number, by doing for example `pip install Pandas==x`i can see that the matching distributions are:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Pandas==x.x.
>   (from versions: 0.1, 0.2b0, 0.2b1, 0.2, 0.3.0b0, 0.3.0b2, 0.3.0,
>   0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.7.0rc1, 0.7.0, 0.7.1, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0rc2, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.9.0, 0.9.1, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.11.0, 0.12.0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.14.0, 0.14.1, 0.15.0, 0.15.1, 0.15.2, 0.16.0, 0.16.1, 0.16.2, 0.17.0, 0.17.1, 0.18.0, 0.18.1, 0.19.0rc1, 0.19.0, 0.19.1, 0.19.2, 0.20.0rc1, 0.20.0, 0.20.1, 0.20.2, 0.20.3, 0.21.0rc1, 0.21.0, 0.21.1, 0.22.0, 0.23.0rc2, 0.23.0, 0.23.1, 0.23.2, 0.23.3, 0.23.4, 0.24.0rc1, 0.24.0, 0.24.1, 0.24.2, 0.25.0rc0, 0.25.0, 0.25.1, 0.25.2, 0.25.3, 1.0.0rc0, 1.0.0) No matching distribution found for Pandas==x

This means that Pandas==1.0.0 should be available, however, when I try to install it I get the following error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "/tmp/pip-build-uc6w1vdn/pandas/setup.py", line 42
>     f"numpy >= {min_numpy_ver}",
>                               ^
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
> ```

Because it uses f-string, available from python 3.6 onwards.

Why does pip show incompatible versions? Shouldn't it show only versions I am able to install?

Comment: Pandas 1.0 only supports python 3.6.1 and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, `pip` is showing all of the available versions of the package irrespective of the Python version requirement.

The following part of the [documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers) suggests that:

> Since version 6.0, pip also supports specifiers containing environment
>   markers like so:
>
> ```
> SomeProject ==5.4 ; python_version < '2.7'
> SomeProject; sys_platform == 'win32'
> ```

`python_version` is specified separately from the version of the package.

You can set it in the following way in when running pip (defaults to the interpreter version):

```
pip install --python-version= pandas==
```